# Rearrange triple sublists

Tags: list-manipulation, permutation

Given a set of triple lists (all contain element `9`!)

```
tripel = {{5, 10, 9}, {4, 9, 3}, {3, 9, 8}, {4, 5, 9}, {9, 10, 8}}
```

I would like to rearrange `tripel` to

```
Map[Which[#[[1]] == 9, #, #[[2]] ==9, {#[[2]], #[[3]], #[[1]]}, #[[3]] ==9, {#[[3]], #[[1]], #[[2]]}] &, tripel]
(*{{9, 5, 10}, {9, 3, 4}, {9, 8, 3}, {9, 4, 5}, {9, 10, 8}}*)
```

Is there a more direct and simple way to realize this cyclic permutation in Mathematica?
Thanks!

Comment: Just checking something: should the outcome be `{{9, 5, 10}, {9, 4, 3}, {9, 3, 8}, {9, 4, 5}, {9, 10, 8}}` or is it correct as it is?

Comment: @bmf I think it's correct as it is

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
triples = {{5, 10, 9}, {4, 9, 3}, {3, 9, 8}, {4, 5, 9}, {9, 10, 8}}

NestWhile[RotateLeft, #, First@# =!= 9 &] & /@ triples
```

> {{9, 5, 10}, {9, 3, 4}, {9, 8, 3}, {9, 4, 5}, {9, 10, 8}}

---

**EDIT**

The solution above works if there are more entries per sublist, but will run in a loop if `9` is not present. To improve, additional arguments are needed:

```
triples2 = {{5, 10, 9}, {4, 9, 3}, {3, 9, 8}, {4, 5, 9}, {4, 10, 
   8}, {3, 6, 8, 9, 10}}

NestWhile[RotateLeft, #, First@# =!= 9 &, 1, Length@#] & /@ triples2
```

{{9, 5, 10}, {9, 3, 4}, {9, 8, 3}, {9, 4, 5}, {4, 10, 8}, {9, 10, 3,
6, 8}}

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer. It would be sufficient (in your edit) if only lists containing `9` would be returned!

Comment: I don't know of a way to do it with `NestWhile` unless an `If` is used. But then, it would be easier to pre-filter sublists that don't have a `9`.

Answer (score 8):

Also using [FirstPosition](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FirstPosition.html?q=FirstPosition) with the 3rd (default if no matching) parameter:

```
triples = {{5, 10, 9}, {4, 9, 3}, {3, 9, 8}, {4, 5, 9}, {9, 10, 8}, {1, 2, 3}};
RotateLeft[#, FirstPosition[#, 9, {1}] - 1] & /@ triples

(* {{9, 5, 10}, {9, 3, 4}, {9, 8, 3}, {9, 4, 5}, {9, 10, 8}, {1, 2, 3}} *)
```

Comment: can save 4 characters removing `[[1]]` (+1, of course)

Comment: @kglr Changed it as suggested. Many thanks! :-)

Answer (score 7):

```
tripel = {{5, 10, 9}, {4, 9, 3}, {3, 9, 8}, {4, 5, 9}, {9, 10, 8}};

tripel /. {{a_, 9, c_} :> {9, c, a}, {a_, b_, 9} :> {9, a, b}}
```

{{9, 5, 10}, {9, 3, 4}, {9, 8, 3}, {9, 4, 5}, {9, 10, 8}}

Comment: Thanks, that looks better readable than my `Which`- version

Answer (score 7):

```
RotateLeft[#, PositionIndex[#] @ 9 - 1] & /@ tripel
```

> ```
> {{9, 5, 10}, {9, 3, 4}, {9, 8, 3}, {9, 4, 5}, {9, 10, 8}}
> ```

To generalize to the case where `9` does not appear in some triples, replace `PositionIndex[#] @ 9` with

```
Replace[_Missing -> 1] @ PositionIndex[#] @ 9
```

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps:

```
NestWhile[RotateLeft, #, #[[1]] != 9 &] & /@ tripel
```

yields: {{9, 5, 10}, {9, 3, 4}, {9, 8, 3}, {9, 4, 5}, {9, 10, 8}}

Answer (score 5):

```
 MapThread[RotateLeft,{#,Position[#,9][[All,2]]-1}]&[tripel]

(* {{9,5,10},{9,3,4},{9,8,3},{9,4,5},{9,10,8}} *)
```